# How i can create session for multi imgae on upload?

Tags: php, image-uploading

i have :

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$errors= array();




$im = 1;
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];
    $_SESSION['cropped_image'][$im] = $newimage_name.$file_name;
    $im++; 
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$newimage_name.$file_name)){


            echo $imageLocation1 = $_SESSION["cropped_image"][0];
            echo "<br />";
            echo $imageLocation2 = $_SESSION['cropped_image'][1];


        }
    }

}

}
```

it's working very good for upload imgae and create session, but When i echo session it print 2 times for session 1 in this case :

```
$_SESSION["cropped_image"][0];
```

but 
    echo $imageLocation1 = $_SESSION["cropped_image"][1];

print 1 time which is good.

for example:

1411476445S_l_xHltn94G5k_bTV5__9lESGQD53012.jpg
1411476445S_l_xHltn94G5k_bTV5__9lESGQD53012.jpg
1411476445S_l_xHltn94G5k_bTV5__9lESGQD53113.jpg

Please help me.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION['cropped_image'] starts from an index of 1 so echoing $_SESSION['cropped_image'][0] will do nothing I think you just need to change this:

```
echo $imageLocation1 = $_SESSION["cropped_image"][0];
echo "<br />";
echo $imageLocation2 = $_SESSION['cropped_image'][1];
```

To this:

```
echo $_SESSION["cropped_image"][$im];
echo "<br />";
```

Comment: Is the image being uploaded successfully? Also see my edit to the code and try that

Answer (score 0):

I tried to Unset the session of Image after print theme on the end of my file like:

```
        unset($_SESSION['cropped_image'][0]);
        unset($_SESSION['cropped_image'][1]);
        unset($_SESSION['cropped_image'][2]);
```

and it is working.

Why? because if i do not unset the images session, it stay in memory and print in new upload file.